# Bash command/script to split line on a certain character

Tags: awk, sed

I would like to split the below data to the expected output:

Raw Data:

```
931096|376601|1|ART|AT-2151780724|2151780724|2|102809198|I|CGM44I|MIL3VF03|52576377.3600|PENDING|MO|PEND-INFO|Pend ACS4R|N|N|N|N|N|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|N|NULL|NULL|N|system|NULL|NULL|52576377.3600|1317720|system|2020-02-13 02:00:42|0
931097|375789|1|AYT|AT-2151509210|2151509210|7|102614605|A|CTHGMI|OZF19|444006.6400|APPROVED|NULL|APPROVED|Approved|N|N|N|N|N|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|N|NULL|NULL|N|kg17718|NULL|NULL|0.0000|1317722|system|2020-02-13 02:00:43|0931098|375979|1|AHT|AT-2151780726|2151780726|2|102809199|I|CGMI|MILaesLF11|26312.0000|PENDING|MO|PEND-INFO|Pend ACRES|N|N|N|N|N|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|N|NULL|NULL|N|system|NULL|NULL|26312.0000|1317721|system|2020-02-13 02:00:43|0
931099|376572|1|AT|AT-2151399812|2151399812|5|102673999|I|CG2rMI|WEL44LF15|60991.6956|PENDING|MO|PEND-INFO|Pend ACERS|N|N|N|N|N|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|N|NULL|NULL|N|system|NULL|NULL|0.0000|1317723|system|2020-02-13 02:00:45|0
```

Expected Output:

```
931096|376601|1|ART|AT-2151780724|2151780724|2|102809198|I|CGM44I|MIL3VF03|52576377.3600|PENDING|MO|PEND-INFO|Pend ACS4R|N|N|N|N|N|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|N|NULL|NULL|N|system|NULL|NULL|52576377.3600|1317720|system|2020-02-13 02:00:42|0
931097|375789|1|AYT|AT-2151509210|2151509210|7|102614605|A|CTHGMI|OZF19|444006.6400|APPROVED|NULL|APPROVED|Approved|N|N|N|N|N|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|N|NULL|NULL|N|kg17718|NULL|NULL|0.0000|1317722|system|2020-02-13 02:00:43|0
931098|375979|1|AHT|AT-2151780726|2151780726|2|102809199|I|CGMI|MILaesLF11|26312.0000|PENDING|MO|PEND-INFO|Pend ACRES|N|N|N|N|N|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|N|NULL|NULL|N|system|NULL|NULL|26312.0000|1317721|system|2020-02-13 02:00:43|0
931099|376572|1|AT|AT-2151399812|2151399812|5|102673999|I|CG2rMI|WEL44LF15|60991.6956|PENDING|MO|PEND-INFO|Pend ACERS|N|N|N|N|N|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|N|NULL|NULL|N|system|NULL|NULL|0.0000|1317723|system|2020-02-13 02:00:45|0
```

Basically the \n character is getting lost sometimes in the data and the lines are getting merged. Sometimes more than 1 line gets merged as well (even the opposite happens but we can get to that later).

The data always has 43 columns | separated. The last but one column(42nd) always is a timestamp and the last column is usually 0 or 1.

Trying for the below approach:
If cols > 43
Split 44th column to add \n and print the remaining.
Repeat process until cols=43

`echo "${curr}" | awk -F\| ' { if(NF > 43) {for(i=43;i<NF;i++) "sed '${NR}s/\(^0\)/\1\n/p' $i" }}' filename`

Comment: What do you mean *"the newline is getting lost sometimes"*? If your computer, disks and network are not able to correctly store/process data, there is little point correcting it - it will probably get lost again, surely?

Comment: The usual way with `sed`: write a regex that matches 43 `|` characters with anything in between and a digit. Then insert a newline after the matched string.

Comment: @MarkSetchell we get the data from a different source and they are not able to correct it so we have to before we process it.

Comment: @KamilCuk tried something like this ```echo "${curr}" | awk -F\| '  { if(NF > 43) {for(i=43;i<NF;i++) "sed '${NR}s/\(^0\)/\1\n/p' $i" }}' filename```  But its not exactly working

Comment: @vinaykumar, Please do add your efforts(which you shown in your previous comments) in your question as a Good Practice, comments are not meant for same, btw thanks for showing efforts in form of code.

Comment: @vinaykumar, could you please do lemme know if my solution worked for you in my answer section?

Comment: If column one is always sequential, it might be more reliable in the answers to insert a newline before "$1+1" instead of after "pipe digit" in the case where there are more than 42 fields present.

Comment: The last column is *usually* 0 or 1? I suspect this newline error was caused by someone upstream implementing a solution that *usually* works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

less complex

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"} 
     NF>43 {for(i=43;i<=NF;i+=42) {t=$i; $i=substr(t,1,1) ORS substr(t,2)}}1' file

931096|376601|1|ART|AT-2151780724|2151780724|2|102809198|I|CGM44I|MIL3VF03|52576377.3600|PENDING|MO|PEND-INFO|Pend ACS4R|N|N|N|N|N|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|N|NULL|NULL|N|system|NULL|NULL|52576377.3600|1317720|system|2020-02-13 02:00:42|0
931097|375789|1|AYT|AT-2151509210|2151509210|7|102614605|A|CTHGMI|OZF19|444006.6400|APPROVED|NULL|APPROVED|Approved|N|N|N|N|N|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|N|NULL|NULL|N|kg17718|NULL|NULL|0.0000|1317722|system|2020-02-13 02:00:43|0
931098|375979|1|AHT|AT-2151780726|2151780726|2|102809199|I|CGMI|MILaesLF11|26312.0000|PENDING|MO|PEND-INFO|Pend ACRES|N|N|N|N|N|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|N|NULL|NULL|N|system|NULL|NULL|26312.0000|1317721|system|2020-02-13 02:00:43|0
931099|376572|1|AT|AT-2151399812|2151399812|5|102673999|I|CG2rMI|WEL44LF15|60991.6956|PENDING|MO|PEND-INFO|Pend ACERS|N|N|N|N|N|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|N|NULL|NULL|N|system|NULL|NULL|0.0000|1317723|system|2020-02-13 02:00:45|0
```

following your spec

> If cols > 43 Split <strike>44th</strike> 43th column to add
>   \n and print the remaining. Repeat process until <strike>cols=43</strike> the end.

Comment: this works on the given data but if there is one more line which is merged to the same one then running this twice splits it in the wrong way. Could you please explain what ur doing there as well if you can?

Comment: There's a blank line getting introduced at the end. So running it through ```sed -i '/^$/d' file ``` after this

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples. This solution will take care of inserting new lines even if you have more than 1 occurrences present in your single line too.

```
awk '
match($0,/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\|0/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  if(val){
    num=gsub(/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\|0/,"&")
    while(++count<num){
      sub(/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\|0/,"&\n")
    }
  }
  val=count=num=""
}
1
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

The usual way with sed: write a regex that matches 43 | characters with anything in between and a digit. Then insert a newline after the matched string.

```
sed 's/[0-9]\{6\}\(|[^|]*\)\{41\}|[0-9]/&\n/g ; s/\n$//'
#                                               ^^^^^^^ - remove the leftover newline
#                                       ^ - the matched string
#                                 ^^^^^ - trailing digit
#                                ^ - 42th pipe character
#                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - 41 fields with anything in between
#      ^^^^^^^^^^ - leading 6 digits
```

[tested on repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/DraftySkinnyWorkplace)

Or maybe match 42 pipes with anything in front and a digit::

```
sed 's/\([^|]*|\)\{42\}[0-9]/&\n/g ; s/\n$//'
```

Or match a character after 42 pipes and a digit and insert a newline in between:

```
sed 's/\(\([^|]*|\)\{42\}[0-9]\)\(.\)/\1\n\3/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't trust the source of the data. Maybe it will add another `|` and the number of columns is wrong.
Another approach is guessing that you can trust the timestamp field.
So try to split the line when the field after the timestamp has more dan one character (and split after the first).

```
sed -E 's/([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\|.)(.)/\1\n\2/g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/[^|]*/\n&/44;s/\(|.\)\([^|]*|\)\n/\1\n\2/;P;D' file
```

If there is a 44th field, insert a newline before it. Then remove that newline and insert it following the first character of the 43rd field. Print the first line, delete the first line and repeat.